# Open-Source Shamir Secret Sharing Hardware Implementations in GF

Tags: algorithm-design, secret-sharing, cryptographic-hardware

Is there any hardware implementation of Shamir's secret-sharing method available? I have only go the following two implementations in the existing literature.

1. [Paper 1](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/stamp/stamp.jsp?tp=&arnumber=8342091)
2. [Paper 2](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/stamp/stamp.jsp?tp=&arnumber=6754605)

Anything more in the GitHub or any other spaces especially in GF(2^x)? Any open-source hardware implementation directed towards FPGA will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I did search, however couldn't find one. Could you ask the authors of the papers?

Comment: @kelalaka Thanks for your effort. I am also thinking about asking the authors.